# Should I say "For/ to / me had the same story like you had" or just "Me had the same story"?

Tags: pronouns, subjects

What is the acceptable  way of the following sentences?

> 1) I'll tell you the truth, **for** **me** had the same story that you had
>
> 2) I'll tell you the truth, **To me** had the same story that you had.

Or simply without and addition of prepositions:

> 3) I'll tell you the truth, **Me** had the same story like you had.

Comment: People that vote my answer to negative, can I understand why? It doesn't encourage the people that ask questions to feel comfortable here.  If you think that this is not ok, just tell us / me what is the problem and me correct / edited. your voting doesn't help, but just opposite.

Comment: The merits of anonymous voting have been discussed at length all across the Stack Exchange: on ELL ([here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/413) & [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/460), e.g.); on ELU ([here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6725) and [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6873), e.g.) and on meta.SE (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32226) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198962), e.g.). Don't be intimidated by downvotes, but be resolved to make improved contributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Neither** is acceptable.  The second part of the sentence is a *clause* and needs a subject (to go along with the "had" - the predicate).  "Me" cannot be a subject, the subject would be "I":

> I'll tell you the truth, for ***I*** had the same story [that] you had.

You can omit the 'for' with a slight change of meaning

> I'll tell you the truth, ***I*** had the same story [that] you had.

The '**for**' in the former sentence plays the role of "*because*".  In the latter sentence the two clauses are independent, simply combined into a compound sentence.